# Proving an inequality involving 2 variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

I want to show $$\cosh(xy)\le e^{(x^2y^2)/2}$$

where $\cosh(xy)=\frac{e^{xy}+e^{-xy}}{2}$. I tried differentiating with respect to $x$ in hopes of showing that $\frac{ye^{xy}-ye^{-xy}}{2}\le xy^2e^{x^2y^2/2}$ but that seems more difficult. I know that $x\mapsto e^{xy}$ is concave but I don't see how that can be used here. How can this inequality be shown?

Answer (score 2):

Set $t=xy$ (the two variables are only here for show, since everything is expressed in terms of their product). Then you only need to show
$$
\forall t\in\mathbb{R}, \qquad \frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2} \leq e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}
$$
which you can prove e.g. by studying the function $f\colon t\in \mathbb{R}\mapsto e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} - \frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}$.

Comment: For the last part, there may be a clever argument based on convexity, which I'm not seeing right now. But the brute-force approach based on differentiation will work.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}-\cosh t=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2n}}{2^n n!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{2^n n!}-\frac{1}{(2n)!}\right]t^{2n}\ge0 $ for all $t$

since $(2n)!=(2n)(2n-1)\cdots(n+1)(n!)\ge(2^n)(n!)$ for $n\ge1$,

so the inequality is valid for all $x,y$.

Comment: If it's valid for $xy>0$, it's valid for $xy<0$ as well. Both sides are even. (Also, it only asks for inequality, not strict, so holds fo $0$ too.)

Comment: @ClementC. You're right - I realized this when I read my answer, and I also miscopied the problem.